# Is it to be expected that it will end in a kerfuffle if previous mentioned conditions occur?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

Is this phrase correct? ..."No wonder all the thing ending in a kerfuffle" meaning that if previous mentioned conditions occur, is to be expected it will end in a kerfuffle.

In context: "My neighbour is a blabbing klutz, better don't canoodle when she's around or you will get flummoxed by her barking quackery on morals. No wonder all the thing ending in a kerfuffle."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final sentence should be changed to

> No wonder all things end in a kerfuffle.

meaning "everything ends mixed up".

> It is to be expected that it will end in a kerfuffle.

is a grammatically correct sentence, but the context is important.
It will usually refer to *something* in a previous context which will not end well.

Comment: ..."better don't canoodle when she's around or you will get flummoxed by her barking quackery on morals and involved in a kerfuffle." Is it now more clear?

Comment: or ..."and this is likely to end in a kerfuffle if that happens."

Answer (score 0):

1) ..."better don't canoodle when she's around or you will get flummoxed by her barking quackery on morals and involved in a kerfuffle."

or...

2) ..."and this is likely to end in a kerfuffle if that happens."

Which do you think is better expressed?